# tikzchainprevious undefined

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-chains

I am using the following code for drawing a TikZ chain diagram:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary
{
    arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.pathreplacing,
    positioning,
    shapes,
    shapes.geometric,
    scopes
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Test Frame}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    [
        overlay, remember picture,]
        node distance=.8cm,
        start chain=going below,
    ]
    \draw (current page.center) node (__m_statement)
        [
            anchor=north,
            join,
            font=\bfseries\scriptsize,
            color=black,
            rectangle,
            very thick,
            draw=black,
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=5pt,
        ]
    {User Statement};

\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error when compiling both online at WriteLatex (https://www.writelatex.com/636783sbydyy) or locally with either pdflatex or xelatex:

```
Undefined control sequence. <argument> \tikzchainprevious l.43 \end{frame}
```

What is the TikZ library that I am missing? I could not find that library on the Internet.

Comment: There's an extra `]` after `remember picture,`. Also, you need to add `on chain` to the node.

Comment: Ok, sorry for the mistake. It does not change the result (correcting that does not solve the problem, neither in WriteLatex, nor in local latex compilers).

Comment: You need to add `on chain` to the list of options to node `(__m_statement)`

Comment: Thank you. If you like, post it as an answer to the question because it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an extra `]` after `remember picture,`. Also, you need to add `on chain` to the node.

Removing `]` will allow the key `start chain` to be processed. Adding `on chain` will initialize the first node on the chain, so that `\tikzchainprevious` is defined.